# (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext, NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: uisearchbar, nsmanagedobject

I have an app that displays text saved in core data. On this text I added a `SearchBar` and `SearchDisplayController`. When I prompt inside the `SearchBar` and I type something, immediately I have this

`NSInvalidArgumentException: **'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSManagedObject compare:options:range:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8cb6460'**.`

`0x8cb6460` is a `NSString` variable named `tempSearchStr`.
Here are two blocks of code:

First block

```
- (NSManagedObjectContext *)managedObjectContext
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = nil;
    id delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if ([delegate performSelector:@selector(managedObjectContext)]) {
        context = [delegate managedObjectContext];
    }

    return context;
}
```

Second block

```
- (void)searchInNoteMe
{
    NSString *searchString = self.searchBar.text;

    for (NSString *tempSearchStr in notemearray) {
        NSComparisonResult NSCResult = [tempSearchStr compare:searchString
                                                      options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (NSCResult == NSOrderedSame) {
            [notemearrayfiltered addObject:tempSearchStr];
        }
    }
}
```

Code for `notemearray`:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"NoteMe"];
    notemearray = [[moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                      error:nil] mutableCopy];

    notemearrayfiltered = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:notemearray];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: You are calling a unrecognized method on `tempSearchStr` this is most likely due to it not being an `NSString`, but a `NSManagedObject` (or a sub class) - what does `notemearray` contain? You probably want to access the string attributed you defined in Core data instead.

Comment: 'notemearray' contains text saved from a TextView. I can access to core data for read, save and update text, but I can't search in (sorry for my bad english). Yes, I want to access the strings defined in core data.

Comment: If that was the case you wouldn't be getting this error! If you add the following directly at the start of the `for` loop, what does it output? `NSLog(@"tempSearchStr class: %@", NSStringFromClass([tempSearchStr class]));`

Comment: tempSearchStr class: NSManagedObject

Comment: Yep, so `notemearray` contains your CoreData objects, not strings. Post the code where you populate `notemearray`.

Comment: no need for the comment with the code in it :) What properties have you set up `NoteMe` to have in the core data editor?

Comment: ...ok, no more coded comments...
I set up only two attributes: noteme, timeNote; both type is string.

Comment: Thank you. Now I have in searchBar textDidChange a NSString for a NSRange rangeOfString (this because I want search in all my text and not only in visible text in tableview). Is there a NSManagedObject corresponding "rangeOfString"?

Comment: As I've said before, you need to be working on the attributed of your `NSManagedObject`, not the object itself.

Comment: Yes, something like this:
for (NSManagedObject *note in notemearray) {
        
        NSString *noteString = [note valueForKey:@"noteme"];
        NSRange range = [noteString rangeOfString:searchText
                                    options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
Thank you.

Comment: Yep, same method as I posted in my answer. I'll updated my answer on how to save things back into the `NSManagedObject` too.

Answer (score 0):

`notemearray` contains `NSManagedObject`s and not `NSString`s, that is what the exception is telling you.

You want to call `compare:options:range:` on the `noteme` attribute of your CoreData object.

```
- (void)searchInNoteMe
{
    NSString *searchString = self.searchBar.text;

    for (NSManagedObject *note in notemearray) {
        NSString *noteString = [note valueForKey:@"noteme"];
        NSComparisonResult NSCResult = [noteString compare:searchString 
                                                   options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)
                                                     range:NSMakeRange(0, [searchString length])];
        if (NSCResult == NSOrderedSame) {
            [notemearrayfiltered addObject:note];
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to update the `noteme` attribute on your `NSManagedObject` you can do the following:

```
[note setValue:@"New string" forKey:@"noteme"];
```